# What is the difference between order and correlation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, correlation-functions, topological-order

The concepts of correlation and order are ubiquitous in statistical physics and condensed matter but I have yet to find a reference that makes an order in the confusing terminology.
As far as I understand now -

Long/short/quasi-long range order:-

1. LRO: $$\left<\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\right>\overset{|x-y|r\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}=\left<\sigma(x)\right>\left<\sigma(y)\right>=\left<\sigma(x)\right>^2=const$$
2. Quasi-LRO: $$\left<\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\right>-\left<\sigma(x)\right>\left<\sigma(y)\right>\overset{|x-y|\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}=1/|x-y|^\alpha$$
3. SRO: $$\left<\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\right>-\left<\sigma(x)\right>\left<\sigma(y)\right>\overset{|x-y|r\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}=e^{-\zeta|x-y|}$$

All of the above are given in terms of **correlation functions**:

$$G(x,y)=\left<\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\right>-\left<\sigma(x)\right>\left<\sigma(y)\right>$$
In an ordered phase (LRO), an average behavior of the local degrees of freed is observed (SSB). And not only that the average DOF has a certain value, distant DOF are similar to each other. An unordered phase (SRO) is such that distant DOFs behave differently. Quasi-long rang order is somewhere in the middle with algebraic decay of correlations

1. So how come, for example, Pathria writes this confusing sentence?

   > "Molecules in a low-density vapor are nearly uncorrelated whereas molecules
   > in a dense liquid can be strongly correlated and display short-range order due to their
   > strong steric repulsions but the correlations decay away rapidly at large distances." p. 326.

   How can there be order without correlations, or correlations without order?
2. What is the difference between correlation on order, and when do we observe long/quasi-long/short order, and long/quasi-long/short correlations?
3. Additionaly, how are the above expectation values are defined - are the averaged over the DOFs of a given configuration, or over many realizations of configurations of the same phase?
4. What is the relation between the above classification order and topological phases, namely symmetry protected topological phases, topological insulators, and topologically ordered phases?

Comment: 1) The first statement seems also confusing to me, naively, when speaking about molecules, I would think about something that has a dipole electric moment, so the electic field decays more rapidly, than the Coulomb $1/r^2$, namely, with the $1/r^3$, however, it is still not as fast, as exponential decay. Exponential decay arises in plasma, Debye screening, but it is not the case for dense liquid.

Comment: 2) As for long order - the most prominent example is the magnetic phase, when spins are aligned all at the same direction. Quasi-long order emerges at the point of **continuous phase transition**, correllation functions decay with a power law, and the power is called a **criticial exponent**.    3) The average is defined as *ensemble average*, over a different realisations of the same system , sampled from the given probabiliy distribution.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator  In my personal opinion,  in the statement of Pathria that  "Molecules in a low-density vapor are nearly uncorrelated whereas molecules in a dense liquid can be strongly correlated", the correlated or uncorrelated he mentioned  might be relates to the interaction between molecules. If I'm right, the low-density vapor might be something like the ideal gas where we treat it as no interaction between molecules. And that make sense as you said that the interaction between molecules does not decay as fast as exponential decay.